# echoprint - stopping the service Solr, I lose the database

Tags: python, solr, audio-fingerprinting, echoprint

As I can do to stop the service and tt solr correctly. What I do is restart the PC and then wake up services, but to perform validation of a song, I get a message as if the database has been damaged. I wonder what is the right way to close the service to run and test after songs but not the database is damaged. Greetings and thanks.

1. Start the tts   / usr/local/tokyotyrant-1.1.33/bin/ttservercd echoprint-server/solr/solr
2. java -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/user01/echoprint-server/solr/solr/solr/
   -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=mykey -jar start.jar
3. Ingest new song
4. I stop Solr    java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=mykey -jar start.jar
   --stop

Now, when I start the service and I want to make a song compracion some that I have in the database sends me an error.

Traceback (most recent call last): File "lookup.py", line 51, in lookup (sys.argv [1]) File "lookup.py", line 35, in lookup result = fp.best_match_for_query (decoded) File ".. / API / fp.py ", line 194, in best_match_for_query get_tyrant tcodes = (). multi_get (trackids) File".. / API / pytyrant.py ", line 296, in multi_get raise KeyError (" Missing a result, unusable response in 1.1.10 ") KeyError: 'Missing a result, unusable response in 1.1.10'

How should initiate and terminate service without losing any information.?

Comment: Your problem does not seem to be Solr, but TokyoTyrant. And the key phrase there is "Missing a result, unusable response in 1.1.10". If you search the internet for it, you will find a number of discussions about it, including in specialized groups. That might be a better avenue to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

well I found my mistake and if the ttserver. Thanks Alexandre for that data. Well the right way to make it work would be this

/usr/local/tokyotyrant-1.1.33/bin/ttserver casket.tch

there indicated the name of the on-disk hash, that will make persistent. Then start Solr normally and I can enter and view songs without problems :)